# What argument to give to the function to return results for more than one value?

Tags: r, function, plot, vector

I need to simulate the probabilities that are computed using the function transitionProbability1D from isingLenzMC package. I want to simulate them for 10 values of bF at once and receive a vector of results but still receive only one number and I dont know why. Here is my code

```
N <- 100
conf0 <- genConfig1D(N)
conf1 <- flipConfig1D(conf0)


# transition probability at J=H=1/kBT=1.0, 1= p-ty metropolis 2=glauber
bF <- 1:10
J <- h <- rep(1,10)

# HERE IT DOESNT WORK EVEN THOUGHT bF IS A VECTOR 
transitionProbability1D(bF, conf0, conf1, J, h, 1)
>> 0.298615
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at how to vectorize a function.
On your example, the following would probably give you what you expect:

```
library(isingLenzMC)
N <- 100
conf0 <- genConfig1D(N)
conf1 <- flipConfig1D(conf0)


# transition probability at J=H=1/kBT=1.0, 1= p-ty metropolis 2=glauber
bF <- 1:10
# Here I changed these inputs to single values
J <- h <- 1

# HERE IT DOESNT WORK EVEN THOUGHT bF IS A VECTOR 
transitionProbability1D(bF, conf0, conf1, J, h, 1)
# Vectorize on the first argument
transitionProbability1D_vectorized <- Vectorize(transitionProbability1D, vectorize.args = "ikBT")
# Now there are as many results as input values
transitionProbability1D_vectorized(ikBT = bF, x = conf0, xflip = conf1, J = J, H = h, probSel = 1)
```

You could also use a (`for`) loop!